# Replication error on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

I'm doing merge replication between two SQL Server 2008 machine. But, when I attempt to do any modification on subscriber system, I get the following error.

> *The merge process could not enumerate changes at the 'Subscriber'.
>
>   When troubleshooting, restart the synchronization with verbose 
>   history logging and specify an output file to which to write.
>
>   (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147200999)*

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to log onto the distributor and stop the merge agent.  Then open a command line window and navigate to the folder which has the replication binaries in it (c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\COM\ by default).  Run replmerg.exe and paste in all the values from step 2 of the job which is the replication agent.  Then change the -OutputVerboseLevel from 0 to 1 (the parameter may not be there if it isn't just add it was an value of 1).

This should give you the actual error message so you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is a very [generic error message](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreplication/thread/367b72d3-baad-4a8b-99dd-dde214c16375/).

This could be caused by anything from network timeouts to a lack of system resources.

Some things that have solved this in the past:

- Check your data: Make sure you don't have an IMAGE columns that has empty strings as the value ([see KB280684 for more information](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280684))
- Run DBCC CHECKDB.  If you get errors, use the REPAIR_FAST option.
- Setup your replication again.

Like I mentioned, it's a generic error, so this may be difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: While it's a generic error message it's pretty easy to troubleshoot.  See my answer.